# STM32H7 DMA2D MEM2MEM rectangle coordinates

Tags: stm32, dma

Question: how do I specify rectangle copy parameters of source (x1, x2, width, height) and destination (x2, y2) buffer using DMA2D registers, in memory to memory mode?

My problem is that I cannot specify an offset of initial (x1, y1, x2, y2) points, the transfer always starts at (0,0) on both buffers.

Details:
The device is STM32H743ZIT6 on the NUCLEO-H743ZI board.
I'm struggling to test copy:

1. 2x2 rectangle from Source buffer to Destination buffer (destination coordinates are (1,1)).

The buffers are tables[16] with 16 bit "pixels" (RGB565). They are both put in AXI SRAM.

So the RM0433 (rev.5) states, page 703:

> Memory-to-memory
>   In memory-to-memory mode, the DMA2D does not perform any graphical data
>   transformation. The foreground input FIFO acts as a buffer and the data are transferred
>   from the source memory location defined in DMA2D_FGMAR to the destination memory
>   location pointed by DMA2D_OMAR.
>   The color mode programmed in the CM[3:0] bits of the DMA2D_FGPFCCR register defines
>   the number of bits per pixel for both input and output.
>   The size of the area to be transferred is defined by the DMA2D_NLR and DMA2D_FGOR
>   registers for the source, and by DMA2D_NLR and DMA2D_OOR registers for the
>   destination.

Ok, buffers addreses and format are obvious. DMA2D_NLR seems doing height/width:

> PL[13:0]: **Pixel per lines**
>   Number of pixels per lines of the area to be transferred.
>
> NL[15:0]: **Number of lines**
>   Number of lines of the area to be transferred.

DMA2D_FGOR:

> LO[15:0]: **Line offset**
>   The line offset used for the foreground image, expressed in pixel when the LOM bit is
>   reset and in byte when the LOM bit is set.
>   When expressed in pixels, only LO[13:0] bits are considered, LO[15:14] bits are
>   ignored.
>   This value is used for the address generation. It is added at the end of each line to
>   determine the starting address of the next line.

DMA2D_OOR:

> LO[15:0]: **Line offset**
>   The line offset used for the output expressed in pixel when the LOM bit is reset and in
>   byte when the LOM bit is set.
>   When expressed in pixels, only LO[13:0] is considered, LO[15:14] are ignored.
>   This value is used for the address generation. It is added at the end of each line to
>   determine the starting address of the next line.

What's strange, I can't see LOM bit in CR register in debugger (Keil), cmsis header doesn't have its mask and even I cannot set this bit by direct register write; even though it exists in RM. Hmmmm.

Anyway, I try to palpate how these settings turn out:

```
//tables initialization, __atribute__ thing is for linker script to put these in axi sram
uint16_t __attribute__((section("FRAME_TEST"))) frameSrc[16] = {0xABC0, 0xABC1, 0xABC2, 0xABC3, 0xABC4, 0xABC5, 0xABC6, 0xABC7, 0xABC8, 0xABC9, 0xABCA, 0xABCB, 0xABCC, 0xABCD, 0xABCE, 0xABCF};
uint16_t __attribute__((section("FRAME_TEST"))) frameDest[16] = {0x0001,0x0001,0x0001,0x0001,0x0001,0x0001,0x0001,0x0001,0x0001,0x0001,0x0001,0x0001,0x0001,0x0001,0x0001,0x0001};

RCC->AHB3ENR |= RCC_AHB3ENR_DMA2DEN;
DMA2D->FGMAR= (uint32_t)frameSrc; //filled with 0xABCx
DMA2D->OMAR = (uint32_t)frameDest; //filled with 0x0001
DMA2D->FGPFCCR |= DMA2D_FGPFCCR_CM_1; //RGB565

DMA2D->FGOR = (uint16_t)0x0002; //offset between lines in source buffer
DMA2D->OOR = (uint16_t)0x0002; //offset between lines in destination buffer
DMA2D->NLR = 0x00000002|(0x00000002<<16); //number of lines, pixels per line
DMA2D->CR |= DMA2D_CR_START;
```

This gives me frameDest (formatted in halfwords hex):

```
ABC0 ABC1 0001 0001
ABC4 ABC5 0001 0001
0001 0001 0001 0001 
0001 0001 0001 0001
```

The OOR/FGOR registers work like the line following offset. Any idea what I'm missing in achieving a buffer below?

```
0001 0001 0001 0001
0001 ABC5 ABC6 0001
0001 ABC9 ABCA 0001 
0001 0001 0001 0001
```

Maybe it is not possible to perform it automatically and the offsets must be added manually to buffer pointer registers?

**EDIT:**
Yes, I get desired output with this edit:

```
//10 bytes offset:
DMA2D->FGMAR= (uint32_t)frameSrc+10; //filled with 0xABCx
DMA2D->OMAR = (uint32_t)frameDest+10; //filled with 0x0001
```

Though it seems my idea about this controller was flawed.

Comment: It seems that you will have to calculate both start addresses yourself. Then, for each line, `# of pixels per line` are transfered and `line offset` pixels are skipped, hence, `# of pixels + line offset` must be the total number of pixels per line in the image.

Comment: A one-line introduction at the top of the question explaining what you're asking about would be nice. Is this some sort of video / graphic application?